# Find cluster of points which are in the close proximity of 10 meters in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have one table which has a large number of points in the column(name as geom). I want to get all those points that are in close proximity to 10 meters. Not close to the specific point but the clusters of points in close proximity to each other. What will be the query of PostGIS for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you looking to points in proximity of a specific point or do you want to find all clusters of points in close proximity to each other?

Comment: All clusters of the points

Comment: So this is a question about spatial clustering, not a question about distance calculations. I vote to reopen the question. I suggest the author edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: Postgis has several clustering algorithms implemented. For example loot at the  DBSCAN implementation https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html